# How to phrase rails instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have a `Lines` model which uses the `ancestry` gem.

```
A line can have children and parent lines.
```

I have a `Miniatures` model.

```
Lines has_many Miniatures through the Minilines table.
```

In my Lines views I can show all associated miniatures for that Line. That works.

What I'd like to be able to do is show all associated miniatures for that line AND it's children.

It needs to use distinct true or uniq in case a miniature is associated with a Line and one of it's subtree Lines.

With some talking to someone working on the ancestry gem I put the following in my view:

```
 <% Miniature.select('distinct *').joins(:lines).where(@line.subtree_conditions).each do |miniature| %>
    <%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %><br />
 <% end %>
```

He didn't think my problem was a problem with the gem, rather a rails problem.

What that code does is make a link to a miniature (correct) but with the `name` and `id` of the line that that miniature belong to, rather than the `name` and `id` of the miniature. After a lot of fiddling around I am so close to getting it to work.

I changed the code to this

```
<% Line.select('distinct *').joins(:miniatures).where(@line.subtree_conditions).each do |miniature| %>
    <%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %><br />
<% end %>
```

It now outputs the correct looking thing. The `name` of the miniature. It also has the correct `miniature_id` but for is linking, bewilderingly, to a `line` path rather than a `miniature` path. For instance it shows the name of miniature number 3 but links to `localhost:3000/lines/3`.

I'll keep fiddling with it but if anyone can see the exact problem I'll be over the moon.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code block, the records being returned are NOT `Miniature` objects, they are `Line` objects - that's the class you queried, that's the class you'll get. :)

In the first case, I'd guess that `Line` has `id` and `name` columns which are shadowing the ones coming from `Miniature`. Try this instead: `Miniature.uniq.joins(:lines).where(@line.subtree_conditions)` which will give you a SELECT that explicitly targets only the fields from the miniatures table.

Comment: Yes that works. I found it weird that it didn't work when it read <% `Miniature.select('distinct *').joins(:lines).where(@line.subtree_conditions).each do |miniature| %>` but I guess the select distinct stuff messed it up. Anyway this works and thank you so much. Allows me to get on with project. Fantastic.